# Using toga.slider, slide between different images

Tags: python, beeware

So I am attempting to create a program using Toga which will allow the user to view different images based on a slider. This is done by using ImageView to retrieve the image from a URL. However, each image has a different URL address (a number is different), so I created a variable which should allow for the program to upload the new image as I slide between each tick mark. However, all I have been able to achieve is the correct format for the tick mark outputs and the initial image loaded for every tick (which is dependent on the starting value). Anyone have any tricks up their sleeve to help me? I would appreciate it!

```
def sliderFunction(widget):

            self.timeZoneValue1 = self.timeZone1.value[:-1] #formats one of the variables
            
            x = int(slider.value) 
            if x < 10:
                x = '%03d'%(int('00') + x) #formats variable
            else:
                x = '%03d'%(int('0') + x)
            print(x)

            try:
                self.home_box5.remove(view) #tried to remove the image before uploading
            except:
                pass

            view = toga.ImageView(image = 'http://www./forecast/{}/{}{}/{}/{}{}_{}_{}_{}.png'.format(self.modelDeterministic.value, self.day1.strftime('%Y%m%d'), self.timeZoneValue1, self.zone, self.modelDeterministic.value, self.zone, self.height, self.option, str(x)))

#str(x) is the variable which should control the output of the new image, which is based                   #on the slider.value
            
            self.home_box5.add(view)
            
            
            
            
        slider = toga.Slider(on_change = sliderFunction, tick_count = 61, range = (0,60), value = 0)
        
        self.home_box5.add(slider)
```

I have tried using the try function (as above), for loops (as below), if statements, and yield 0.1. The same image is used for every tick value. If I start at value = 30, then all the ticks will have that picture. It is almost as if I cannot change the value of view and the program does the initial image for all ticks. Is there a way to override this?

```
viewAll = []
        for i in range(60):
            self.timeZoneValue1 = self.timeZone1.value[:-1]
            
            x = int(i)
            if x < 10:
                x = '%03d'%(int('00') + x)
            else:
                x = '%03d'%(int('0') + x)

            view = toga.ImageView(image = 'http://www./forecast/{}/{}{}/{}/{}{}_{}_{}_{}.png'.format(self.modelDeterministic.value, self.day1.strftime('%Y%m%d'), self.timeZoneValue1, self.zone, self.modelDeterministic.value, self.zone, self.height, self.option, str(x)))
            
            viewAll.append(view)
    
      
        def sliderFunction(widget):
            for i in range(60):
                self.home_box5.add(viewAll[i])
         
            
        slider = toga.Slider(on_change = sliderFunction, tick_count = 61, range = (0,60), value = 0)
        
        self.home_box5.add(slider)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the line `self.home_box5.remove(view)` is using the `view` variable before it's been assigned, so it will always raise a NameError, which your code is catching and ignoring.

If you only need to display one image at a time, then instead of recreating the ImageView every time the slider moves, you could reuse the same ImageView and just change its image, like this:

```py
        def sliderFunction(widget):
            ... 
            image_view.image = toga.Image('http://...')
            
        slider = toga.Slider(on_change = sliderFunction, tick_count = 61, range = (0,60), value = 0)
        self.home_box5.add(slider)

        image_view = toga.ImageView()
        self.home_box5.add(image_view)
```

In the second example, the `sliderFunction` doesn't check `slider.value`, so obviously it won't be affected by the slider position.

Comment: Thanks for replying @mhsmith! Can you clarify what is happening in the code? From my understanding, when I image_view.image- this creates the image. However, the line 'image_view = toga.ImageView()' has me confused- how does this not delete the image created and call image_view.image? 

Also, what is the point of slider.on_change- in my head, it is upon sliding the slider, something new shows. Why is it necessary to add the image outside of the definition? Doesn't this contradict the point of needing a definition?

Comment: The context of your original code wasn't clear, but I assumed it was contained within the `startup` function of a `toga.App`. subclass, so I wrote my answer in the same way. This means the `ImageView` is created once, during startup. The `sliderFunction` which changes the view's image is not called during startup, but is called later, every time the user moves the slider.

Comment: Makes sense. I unfortunately kept getting the error message- parameter not valid. However, I realized in the try example, the removing of 'image_view' was incorrect- I needed to make the variable a global variable; this allowed for the function to remove the first image and input the new image. Thank you for responding and getting me to figure out my error!